# Next year is 2023. The next year is 2024. The next year is 2025

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I know this is correct:
*The next item is 3*.
*The following item is 4*.
*The following item is 5*.
Call these three lines above variant № **(1)**.

I know this is incorrect:
*The next item is 3*.
*The next item is 4*.
*The next item is 5*.
Call these three lines above variant № **(2)**.

That is, in enumerating items, one variant is correct, the other is not.

---

I know this is correct:
*Next year is 2023*.
*The following year is 2024*.
*The following year is 2025*.
Call these three lines above variant № **(3)**.

an example from [a link](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/92355/312479):
Boss: *Where are we at with long term planning*?
Me: *I would like to start planning for **next year***. (2023)
Boss: *2023? What about after that*?
Me: *No problem, I will also start planning for **the next year** too*. (2024)

Therefore, I can add two more same lines here:
Boss: *2024? What about after that*?
Me: *No problem, I will also start planning for **the next year** too*. (2025)

Hence, I can reduce all the lines to:
*Next year is 2023*.
*The next year is 2024*.
*The next year is 2025*.
Call these three lines above variant № **(4)**.

Is (4) correct?

If the answer is "no", then why is it incorrect, whereas the example is correct?
If the answer is "yes", then why, with time, are both variants correct whereas, not with time, only one variant is correct?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your second example.

Comment: @KateBunting Do you mean "_Next year is 2023. The next year is 2024. The next year is 2025._" is correct?

Comment: I meant _The next item is 3 - the next item is 4_ etc., but it would apply to years as well. We say _the followng year_ to refer to the one after the year we have just been talking about.

Comment: @KateBunting I enumerated the variants for convenience. Do you mean: (2) & (4) are both correct? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking because you want to learn how to use *[ "(the) next following" + noun ]* correctly in general, or because you looking for correct and natural wording to talk to your boss about the new few years?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant.

Comment: @gotube 1) I have no boss. As you can see, the example is from the link I placed before this example. It's not of my own composition. 2) I asked because at first I thought (4) is incorrect but then I saw the example about boss and began thinking maybe (4) is correct. 3) As to the other three variants - (1), (2) and (3) - I decided to write them in order that you see all my thoughts about this issue. || Since my post seemed unclear to you, what would you recommend me so that it's more clear?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see these as "correct" or "incorrect" but merely unnecessarily confusing.

"Next year" is generally understandable  (although there are doubts). Speaking of "the following year" is somewhat confusing, but probably understandable,  but then talking about "the following year" (to refer to the year following the following year) is too much.

I'd just use absolute dates:

> Boss: Where are we at with long term planning?
> Me: I would like to start planning for next year. (2023)
> Boss: 2023? What about after that?
> Me: No problem, I will also start planning for 2024 too.